# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement on JSONResponse

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

I am getting this kind of error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

I don't know what causes the error but I have this code here:

```
(function pollschedule(){
    $.ajax({type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/get/schedule/1/",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }, 
    complete: pollschedule, timeout: 5000});
})();
```

In case you might need to see what http://127.0.0.1:8080/get/schedule/1/ is:

```
def get_schedule(request, sid):
    schedule = Schedule.objects.filter(id=sid, date=datetime.datetime.now()).values('id', 'sched__name', 'date', 'time')
    sched_collection = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i in schedule:
        sched_collection[i['sched__name']].append(i)

    return JsonResponse({"schedule" : dict(sched_collection)})
```

And returns this:

```
{"schedule": {"CWW": [{"date": "2016-11-11", "time": "17:10:10"}]}}
```

The error points the semi-colon after "schedule" in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) is not [JSON](http://json.org/). Your response is JSON, but you've told jQuery to expect JSONP.

Either make the response valid JSONP, or update the code doing the retrieval to expect JSON. (Note that if you do the latter, you will run into cross-origin issues unless the page you're running the ajax from is also on `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.)

Comment: Good catch, I missed the datatype there.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I changed the dataType to json and you're right i ran into cross-origin and been taken care. now my prob is why is it not displaying on the template? sorry for asking for more.

Comment: @JanWilmar: Search this site for the "same origin policy" (SOP) and "cross-origin resource sharing" (CORS) and more about JSONP.